# Dynamic ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a data table that contain different job genres and their ids. I wnat all the genres to show as a mMltipleChoiceField in broswer , so i tried

```
 keyword=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False, queryset=JobGenre.objects.all())
```

it wont show job genres , instead it shows "JobGenre.object" in all the options.what should i do in this case?

the error i got from select a jobgenre:´and i must selected at least one option, it seems like required=False doesn't work neither

```
  ValueError at /register/
  Cannot assign "[<JobGenre: rengøring>]": "Worker.keyword" must be a "JobGenre" instance.


 Request Method:

 POST
 Request URL:

 http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/



 Django Version:

  1.4.3
```

Exception Type:

ValueError

```
 Exception Value:

 Cannot assign "[<JobGenre: rengøring>]": "Worker.keyword" must be a "JobGenre" instance. 


 Exception Location:

 C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py in __set__, line 366



 Python Executable:

 C:\Python27\python.exe



 Python Version:

 2.7.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a `__unicode__` defined on JobGenre?

```
class JobGenre(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: but it seems like it return the jobgenre instead of the jobgenre_id, it gives me an value error

Comment: It seems you have a `Worker` model which has a fk to `JobGenre`. So, you need to set `worker.keyword` as an instance of JobGenre. `ModelMultipleChoiceField` return a list and it seems you are trying to assign the list to `worker.keyword`.

Comment: **worker** has a manytomanyfield to **JobGenre**. Django has automatically create a table(job_genre, it has id, job_id and jobgenre_id columns) to relate those two tables. how can i asign the chosen job genre values to the database?